# Number theory to estimate lower bound of S-Matrix?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematics, s-matrix-theory

I recently worked on the following idea:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325724/eigenvalue-of-an-euler-product-type-operator

Edit: And realised it was more probable to be used in Quantum field theory.

### Summary of the idea

We represent numbers by infinite dimensional matrices such as $3$ will have all $0$s except the $1$st row will have a $1$ in the third column, the $2$nd row will have a $1$ in the $6$th row and the $r$th row and $3r$th column also have $1$s:

$$ \hat 3  = | 1 \rangle \langle 3 | + | 2 \rangle \langle 6 | + | 3 \rangle \langle 9 | + \dots = \begin{bmatrix}
    0       &0 & 1        &0 & 0& \dots & 0 \\
    0       &0 & 0 &0       &0 & 1 & \dots & \\
    \vdots \\
    0      & 0 & 0 & \dots 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Similarly we can define $\hat 2$:

$$ \hat 2 = | 1 \rangle \langle 2 | + | 2 \rangle \langle 4 | + | 3 \rangle \langle 6 | + \dots =\begin{bmatrix}
    0       &1 & 0        &0 & 0& \dots & 0 \\
    0       &0 & 0 &1       &0 & 0 & \dots & \\
    0       &0 & 0 &0       &0 & 1 & \dots & \\
    \vdots 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

One notices that these numbers obey multiplication

$$ \hat 6 = \hat 3 . \hat 2 = \hat 2 . \hat 3$$

where the $r$th row of the $6r$th column has a $1$

One can also use this to define an Euler like product formula:

$$ \hat \zeta (s) = \hat 1  + \hat 2^s + \hat 3^s + \dots = (1- \hat 2^s)^{-1}(1- \hat 3^s)^{-1}(1- \hat 5^s)^{-1} \dots$$

Note: $\zeta(1) |\lambda \rangle  =  \sum|\text{factors of } \lambda \rangle$

### My Observation

Let us define the following ladder operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$ from quantum mechanics:

$$ A^\dagger|n \rangle = | n+1 \rangle$$

Now we make the following observation:

$$ \langle m | A^{\dagger s} (1 - A^\dagger)^{-1}|n \rangle \geq \langle m |(\hat \zeta(1) - \sum_{r=1}^s \hat r)|n \rangle  $$

### Question

Given the field operators can be expressed as annihilation and creation operators. Can we get a lower bound on the $S$ matrix?

$$S(a^\dagger, a) \geq S'(\hat \zeta,\hat \zeta^\dagger) $$

Comment: related question by OP: [What is the Hamiltonian of this number theoretic system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/371985/84967).

Comment: Reason for downvote?